# Season dummies in R

Tags: r, time-series, categorical-data, arima

I have heating power data from one year (8670 observations). I also have regressors for day length and temperature (8670 observations also).

I would like to add seasonality with 24h (1 day)  168h (1 week) periods to an ARMA model. Is there an effective way to construct a this kind of seasonal matrix (with day length and temperature data appended to; so a $8670\times(167+2)$ matrix). The application where I would use this is the `auto.arima` functions xreg argument.

Comment: So your question is how to write code for constructing this matrix?

Comment: Hmmm I was thinking of an own column for each hour of the week (so 167+2).

Comment: Please add a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1217536) for people to work with.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about how to use R without a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save your heating power series `x` as a `ts` object specifying frequency equal to 168. Then run `seasonaldummy(x)` (from the "forecast" package) to get a $8670 \times 167$ matrix with dummies for each hour in the week (the $168^{th}$ column is missing as is normal with dummies, so that the last hour of the week forms the basis level). Combine the seasonal dummies with the temperature and the length of the day variables to form the `xreg` to be used in `auto.arima`.

```
x=ts(x,freq=168,start=c(2014,1)) # start was chosen arbitrarily
dummies=seasonaldummy(x)
xreg=cbind(dummies,temperature,daylength)
```

Comment: Thanks! I got `x=ts(Power,freq=168,start=(2010,1))
Error: unexpected ',' in "x=ts(Power,freq=168,start=(2010,"` with what you suggested. Power is variable name for numeric vector of my heating power series $(1:8760)$. I don't know why that didn't work. But what worked was: `dummies = seasonaldummy(ts(1:8760,freq=168,start=1))`. It created large matrix with dimensions $8760\times167$ as I wanted :)

Comment: Sorry! I forgot a letter "c" after `start=`. Now fixed in the answer.